# Some problem about the algorithm of merging two lists

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, data-structures

I have some problem when I practice writing the algorithm of merging two lists.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> list1,list2;
    int tmp;
    cin>>tmp;
    while(tmp!=-1){
        list1.push_back(tmp);
        cin>>tmp;
    }
    cin>>tmp;
    while(tmp!=-1){
        list2.push_back(tmp);
        cin>>tmp;
    }
    vector<int> list3(list1.size()+list2.size());
    vector<int>::iterator iter1=list1.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator iter2=list2.begin();
    while(iter1!=list1.end()&&iter2!=list2.end()){
        if(*iter1<*iter2){
            list3.push_back(*iter1);
            iter1++;
        }
        else{
            list3.push_back(*iter2);
            iter2++;
        }
    }
    while(iter1!=list1.end()){
        list3.push_back(*iter1);
        iter1++;
    }
    while(iter2!=list2.end()){
        list3.push_back(*iter2);
        iter2++;
    }
    if(list3.size()==0) cout<<"NULL";
    for(int i=0;i<list3.size();i++){
        cout<<list3[i];
        if(i!=list3.size()-1){
            cout<<" ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**console input:**

1 3 5 -1

2 4 6 8 10 -1

**expected output result:**
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10

**actual output result：**
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 8 10

Comment: So what did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: constructing vector like this vector<int> list3(list1.size()+list2.size()); fills it with zeroes for given size, consider changing this line to vector<int> list3;

Comment: Consider reading the documentation, of [constructor of `std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), and [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve). They do not do the same thing, and it seems, that you wanted to use `std::vector::reserve`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
vector<int> list3(list1.size()+list2.size());
```

creates a vector of type `int` and inserts `list1.size()+list2.size()` default contructed elements. You want to create an empty vector of type `int` and reserve memory for `list1.size()+list2.size()` elements. Use

```
vector<int> list3;
list3.reserve(list1.size()+list2.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> list3(list1.size()+list2.size());
```

should be

```
vector<int> list3;
```

The first constructor initializes the vector with N+M elements, all initialized to 0, and `push_back` appends more elements at the end. See [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for more information about std::vector constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Replace
`vector<int> list3(list1.size()+list2.size())`;

with    `vector<int> list3;`

When you initialize the Vector with a size of X you will have X elements with the value 0. Then you use `list3.push_back(Y);` which will add the Element Y at the end of the vector. 
If you declare an empty vector and use `list3.push_back(Y);` you wil have only one element Y in the vector.